# What are these abbreviations in Wills and Administrations of Isle of Wight, Virginia?

Tags: 17th-century, probate-records, virginia, abbreviations

I see entries like this one on [page 20](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/49403/FLHG_WillsAdminIsleWightCnty-0019/117100) of Wills and Administrations of Isle of Wight County, Virginia, 1647-1800:

> HIGGINS, Roger: Leg. mother Mary Lupo; at the death of mother my cattle at Edward Millers and Thomas Wombwells to be divided between my brother James Higgins and my Godson Roger Hodges; to my brother Robert Hodge's eldest son; to his second son Elias; to his third son Roger; to James Lupo; to Ann the wife of Nicholas Ogburne. Brother Robert Hodges Ex. D. April 16, 1672. R. Aug. 10, 1672. Wit: Edmond Prime, Nicholas Ogburne. Page 113

What do these abbreviations mean?  I've listed my guesses:

- Leg. — Legal
- D.  — Death
- Ex. — Executor
- R. — (Unsure what this subsequent date would be.)
- Wit. — Witness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abbreviations are as follows:

- Leg. - legacy, legacies OR Legatee (the person receiving a legacy)
- D. - Death or dated (surely death in this example)
- Ex. - Executor
- R. - Register: sometimes this is date, register number and folio number but here it is just the date.
- Wit. - Witnesses

Comment: Do you have a source for these? This would be a better answer if you cited a source.